# Docker - Problems Installing Imagick

Tags: docker, joomla, imagemagick, docker-compose, php-5.6

I am running a php5.6-apache container with a php application inside it. One of my pages shows up completely blank. When I check the logs using `docker logs -f mycontainer`, I get these errors:

```
sh: 1: compgen: not found 
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/convert: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/convert: No such file or directory
```

I know these relate to imagemagick, which is installed via the dockerfile below and used on some site pages; however, there are a few that still show up blank.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libmagickwand-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl install imagick-3.4.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2ensite default-ssl
RUN a2enmod ssl

EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80
```

Things that did not work:
Using `RUN apt-get install imagemagick` throws an error saying that imagemagick is not a package.

Comment: Try using `aptitude update && aptitude install imagemagick` and see how it goes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using `RUN aptitude update && aptitude install imagemagick` gives me the error: `/bin/sh: 1: aptitude: not found`

Comment: I don't understand that. `php:5.6-apache` is based on `debian:jessie` and it should have `aptitude`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hxYLTEc I'm not sure

Comment: Try to install `apt-get install r-cran-rcompgen` because is not finding `compgen`

Comment: I an unable to locate package error if I do that

Comment: Recent versions of ImageMagick have replaced the various IM commands (`convert`, `identify`...) by `magick {command}`: `magick convert`, `magick identify`...